# Hex Representation in Mathematica and Python

Tags: python, binary

I want to convert a code from *Mathematica* to Python.

I am using the following code to convert a code to hexadecimal, binary and so on:

```
    BinaryWrite[*file*, 8192, "Integer16"]
```

But I'd like to see the hex representation, so I am using this code:

```
BaseForm[8192, 16]
```

So I get the following answer:

$2000_{16}$

I am trying to convert this program to Python. If I use `hex(8192)` I get `0x2000`.

Is *Mathematica* writing the hex file as `2000` or `0x2000`? Can I just use `hex(number)` in Python?

Comment: "Integer16" has nothing to do with hexadecimal, it tells Mathematica to output the number as a signed 16 bit integer. [Reading integers from binary file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163459/reading-integers-from-binary-file-in-python)

Comment: Ah, I think that's my problem, but I still don't understand completely. I even searched more about this. So how would it be printed a binary as a "Integer16" or as a "Integer32"? Which function can I use to see the result in those different binaries?

Comment: for instance: `ImportString[ExportString[31, "Integer32"], "Bit"]` However if you just want to get your data from mathematica I think the easiest is to `Export["data.csv", data]` and use the [Python csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html`)

Comment: explains the stray " 0x" in the python form: ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218164/python-integer-to-hexadecimal-extra-characters

Comment: Thanks, @ssch, but I want to convert a binary compiler to Python, since the other person that needs that do not have Mathematica. I thin `bin(np.int16(31))` should be the same as ImportString[ExportString[31, "Integer32"], "Bit"]`. What do you think?

Comment: @Zoher Not really, compare their outputs :)

Comment: pythons bin() strips the lead zeros (hence doesnt care what storage size numpy uses for small numbers). Otherwise I get the same results, though there could be byte ordering differences as well depending on your system

Answer (score 3):

`IntegerString[]` is the equivalent of hex() in python..

```
IntegerString[8192,16] -> "2000"
```

Not sure what you mean by "hex file", one doesnt normally write the ascii hex digits to a file, though you might want to look at a hex dump of your binary file and compare with the above for debugging purpose.

Worth a note, IntegerDigits gives a "BigEndian" representation, regardless of your native machine byte ordering (as does python's hex()), you may need to reverse order if you want to compare with a little endian file:

// addressing your comment "Integer32" gives you a 32 bit, or 8 byte binary representation
which can handle numbers larger than 2^16-1 (well 2^15-1 for signed integers).  To "see" such in "hex" you use the same function, ie

```
IntegerString[2999999999,16]  -> "b2d05dff"
```

You can verify python's hex() gives the same result.  Note the 16 here is the base (hex) not the binary bit length.  Indeed mathematica can handle arbitrarily large numbers so,

```
IntegerString[99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999, 16]
 -> "10b46c6cdd6e3e0828f4db456ff0c8e9fffffffffffff"
```

which would be ~360 bits in a binary (base 2) representation.

These things are worth understanding if you are dealing with large data sets, as binary file io is typically much faster than ascii based.

Comment: Thanks, @george2079, but I noticed that I do not need a hex but a bin with signed 16-bit and signed 32-bit. I think it's a bit more difficult than convert to hex or base 32.

Comment: no its not difficult at all, `BinaryWrite[]` supports both formats no worries --- what problem are you having exactly ?

Comment: Now I understood what is this `Integer16`. What I need to do is to find an equivalent way in Python to `BinaryWrite[...,"Integer16(32)"]`. Do you have an idea?